# How to repeat a Unique Id for each date row?

Tags: mysql

**I have data like this :-**

In Table A :-

```
Date
01-01-2019              
02-01-2019
03-01-2019
04-01-2019
```

and In Table B:-

```
UniqueId
AABB
BCCC
FGGG
```

Now I want to repeat each uniqueid for each date like this :-

```
AABB 01-01-2019
AABB 02-01-2019
AABB 03-01-2019
AABB 04-01-2019,
```

in similar manner for other ids also.

Is someone know how to achieve this ???

Answer (score 2):

Use a cross join:

```
SELECT
    b.UniqueId,
    a.Date
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN TableB b
ORDER BY
    b.UniqueId,
    a.Date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tableB
cross join tableA
```

Answer (score 1):

use cross join

```
select uniqueid,Date
from tableA cross join tableB
```